# Binary Operations with Axiomatic Systems

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

Give an example for a set $G$ and a binary operation which does these:

1. The set is closed under the binary operation.
2. The binary operation is associative.
3. The binary operation has a neutral element.
4. There exists at least one element that does not have an inverse.

In other words, this is almost a group except the axiom about existence of inverses is negated.

I have really tried thinking about it for a long time (apx. 5 hours) and haven't got any idea yet.

Comment: So you want an example of a group such that the binary operation does not allow for any element to have an inverse? That contradicts the definition of group, i.e., that is not a group

Comment: That's why I wrote "set/group".
I was unsure, in whether it will stay a group if we remove that "axiom" or not.

Comment: Do you have any hint / kickstart / idea for a set and a binary operation that could do all that "Axioms"?

Comment: I wonder if there's a language problem rather than a math problem here. As @AirMike points out, the existence of an identity (neutral element) shows the identity has an inverse, so the the statement that 'for all x, x has no inverse' is false the moment you have an identity. But maybe item 4 really means "there isn't an inverse for EVERY element of the set", or, rewritten "there's some element that has no inverse." Then the problem makes sense and becomes do-able.

Comment: @JohnHughes I completely agree! Maybe there’s some sort of mistake in the point $4.$

Comment: @JohnHughes I completely understand you, I just double checked that, and it seems that I was right. basically, let's suppose we have set $A$, and for each $x \in A$, $x$ doesn't have an inverse.

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko but if there is an identity, then we necessarily have an element with an inverse, which contradicts the point $4...$

Comment: Natural number with addition ?

Comment: If you want to negate the existence of inverse axiom it should read "There exists **at least** one element that does **not** have an inverse". What you have written seems to state that **all** elements do not have inverses, and this is a much stronger statement.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA , Hey, What do you mean in Natural Number with addition? 
Did you mean the set $N$ (All the Natural Positive Numbers excluding 0) with the binary operation + (Addition)?

Comment: @Somos , okay, So supposing I said "There exists at least one element that doesn't not have an inverse", Which set and binary operation could I use?

Comment: @MaxIlyouchenko check my edited answer for that

Comment: Obviously, $0$ must be included: Axiom 3.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay, thank you!

Comment: Maybe we have an issue with the translation of Ax.4... May it be: "not every element has an inverse" ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Most likely, I will change that ASAP. Anyways, this question is considered as Solved from my side. 
I would like to thank you very much for answering and helping me out.

Comment: Ok, now that you have explained the context of the question, the answer is clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose such a set (say $S$) and binary operation (say $*$) exists. Let’s derive a contradiction.

We are assuming that we have an identity, say $e.$ So for any $a \in S$ we have that $a * e = a = e * a.$

But if the identity exists, then $e * e = e = e * e,$ and therefore $e$ is its own inverse. Which is a contradiction, because we are assuming that no element has inverse.

Therefore such set and binary operation can’t exist. $\square$

---

Although, if you are looking for a set and a binary operation that satisfies axioms $1$, $2$ and $3$ but not all elements have an inverse (i.e., there is some element with no inverse), then consider the following.

Let $G$ be the set $G = \{0,1\}$ and consider as the binary operation, the usual multiplication.

Then it is straightforward to check that axioms $1$, $2$ and $3$ hold and not every element has an inverse (consider the element $0$ that doesn’t have an inverse under multiplication).

Comment: Uhm, Strange, I am requested to prove that it ACTUALLY DOES exists.

Comment: Well in fact, It should be in axiomatic system.
So my real mission is to prove that axiom 4 (Every element doesn't have an inverse) is independent, so, all the axioms shouldn't change, even if axiom 4 is "disabled".

Comment: But these axioms arise in what context? In some particular structure?

Comment: Well, basically, the problem is like follows:
We have the four axioms of a group (1. Closure, 2. Associativity, 3. Neutral Element, 4. Each element has an Inverse element).
The first mission was to show that we have a model, which does all that axioms, which I showed in no problem.
The second mission was to prove that axiom 4 is independent. 
Which I thought I could show, by showing a set and a binary operation which do all the axioms, but the fourth (Each element has an Inverse element).

Comment: Hum ok! First note that, as I pointed out, if the forth axiom fails, we don’t a have a group. Second, aren’t you looking for some set and binary operation such that not every element has an inverse (i.e., there is some element that has no inverse?)

Comment: If it is that, then you can simply consider the set $G = \{0,1\}$ with the multiplication

Answer (score 3):

A very good answer to your question is to consider **any** field with multiplication operation. This operation is required to
satisfty the first three axioms because that comes from the definition of a field. However, since there is no field with exactly one element, every field has a zero element which can **not** have a multiplicative
inverse.

Comment: Thank you for that useful answer!
Helped me!